# A route named 'DefaultApi' is already in the route collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

This question may seems duplicate but this is slightly different. 
In all other question in SO I had noticed that they have multiple routes registered. but in my case I have just one route.

I am creating asp.net webapi (framework 4.5) and have just one route in RegisterRoutes() method -

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            url: "rest/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

Then why is it throwing error?

```
A route named 'DefaultApi' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique. Parameter name: name
```

Comment: You added the tag *web-api*. When you use WebApi you add your routes to an instance of `HttpConfiguration`, not `RouteCollection`. Also you use `MapHttpRoute()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fine, I resolved it based on the reply by user3038092. Instead of adding it in the route collection, I added it in HttpConfiguration

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "rest/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 24):

I had a similar issue with adding a route `DefaultApi`. Though the exact 'additional details' message in my `ArgumentException` stack trace was:

```
A route named 'MS_attributerouteWebApi' is already in the route collection.
Route names must be unique.
```

I ofcourse made sure I was adding the `DefaultApi` route only once, but in the end noticed that in `Global.asax`'s `Application_Start` method I was calling the `WebApiConfig.Register(..)` twice, though in the following - not immediately obvious - way:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Another serious case of 'copypasterites'! I simply removed the `WebApiConfig.Register(..)` line and that fixed my issue.

(I am using WEB API 2.0/.NET 5)

Comment: In all the land this is the only place where I found the solution to my problem, buried as a 0 post in some related question.  Good job, thanks!  Up and down for hours, never spotted it.

Answer (score 9):

CAUSE: renaming namespaces without removing associated bin and output files.

SOLUTION: manually delete the **bin** and **obj** folders from the output directory. (cleaning the solution is not enough, some problematic residual files remain causing this problem.)

... that was my experience anyway.

Comment: This was also the solution for me, as I had just done a bulk rename of both the namespace and assembly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVC4 or MVC5 application.
Then put your Route Configuration in

WebApiConfig.cs and

also check route name should be unique in both files i.e RouteConfig.cs and WebApiConfig.cs

Answer (score 0):

I see that you call the controller but you do not give the controller name like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            url: "rest/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller="Home",action="Index",id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

that means you regist HomeContrller for the Index view,

Comment: No, that does not mean you register the HomeController for web. Controllers do not need to be explicit registered. The **default** argument is for **default** values, when a route is missing that particular argument.

Comment: do you have use Areas in ASP.net ? if not, it can not have more than one routest

Comment: @traibui, I don't have home controller and not even areas in my project. moreover, even if it is related to the controllername, the error I mentioned surely doesn't match with the solution you suggested. but anyways thanks for your suggestion somewhere it may help to someone else