# What I am doing wrong? Trying to get response from the API

Tags: c#, api, model-view-controller

I am trying to get any response from my API. I have read a lot but any way get 404 (The resource cannot be found.)
Here is my code

```
Web.config:

<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index">
    </forms>
</authentication>
```

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes



    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );


    // webapi return json
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
}
```

ApiController:

```
public class MyAppApiController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Test()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Success = true, bbb = "assssdfv[spld[ssadf[ps" });
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Login(LoginViewModel loginVM)
    {
        var url = this.Url.Link("Default", new { Controller = "AccountController", Action = "Login", model = loginVM});
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Success = true, RedirectUrl = url });
    }
}
```

I am using Google Chrome Simple REST client for testing:

1. Run my VS as administrator
2. Debug my app (localhost:12345 opens with my site)
3. Paste in Google Chrome Simple REST client:

   ```
   http://localhost:12345/api/Test
   ```

   and run GET => result 404 (not found resource)
4. Paste in Google Chrome Simple REST client:

   ```
   http://localhost:12345/api/Login
   ```

   fields data and headers are void and run POST => result 404 (not found resource)

Where is mistake at my code?

Update :

I have updated :

```
   protected void Application_Start()
            {
                AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
                FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
                GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
                RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
                BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
         //removed this: WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            }
```

and after this my code that is

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

works 
 But I still getting 404 error - But the error is new:
`{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:12345/api/Login'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'Login'."}`   My controller name is

```
myProjApiController :ApiController
```

but

```
http://localhost:12345/api/myProjApiController/Login'
```

result in :

```
404 No type was found that matches the controller named 'myProjApiController'
```

Comment: Why did you comment out the route mapping?  If the routes are already defined, what are they?

Comment: Since you have commented out the default route, the `api` part of the URL is no longer recognised. Instead try this: `http://localhost:12345/Test`

Comment: If I am uncommenting it I have got an Additional information: A route named 'MS_attributerouteWebApi' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique. Exception =(

Comment: Side note:  view-models belong in client-side/MVC code, not it your Web API.  Consider mapping to DTO

Comment: http://localhost:12345/Test - not found 404 =(

Comment: Possibly have another route named "DefaultApi" defined incorrectly in another App_Start class?

Comment: Find all "DefaultApi", Subfolders, Find Results 1, Entire Solution, ""
  D:\Prj\myProj\myProj\App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs(20):                name: "DefaultApi",   Matching Lines 1

Comment: Are you calling WebApiConfig twice then in your Global.asax.cs? You wouldn't be the first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24179872/792525

Comment: No. my Global.asax.cs contains only one method and I have provided its full body

Comment: OK, so you've now removed the duplicate. It looks like the URL is not right: the controller name in the URL needs to match the name of the controller class (and you don't need to add 'Controller' in the URL). Try: http://localhost:12345/api/MyAppApi/Login

Comment: localhost:12345/api/MyAppApi/Login   - 404.. Perhaps I need register it in RouteConfig?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a 404 because the routes are not configured, and you're likely to be getting an error when you uncomment the route config because that code is being called twice and is hence trying to define a route with the same name twice.

You've already said that a project-wide search for 'DefaultApi' only returns the result in WebApiConfig.cs. Try the same search for 'WebApiConfig' to look for multiple calls to it.

Alternatively, have a look at these people having the same issue (duplicate routes):

- [A route named "x" is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique. Exception with ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986909/a-route-named-x-is-already-in-the-route-collection-route-names-must-be-unique)
- [A route named 'DefaultRoute' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195286/a-route-named-defaultroute-is-already-in-the-route-collection-route-names-mus)
- [A route named 'DefaultApi' is already in the route collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393265/a-route-named-defaultapi-is-already-in-the-route-collection)